# If elem. mat. E was obtained by executing row operation on I (adding multiple of another row), then EA executes the same row operation on A

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Sorry, the title is not as descriptive as I wanted it to be.

---

The proposition I would like to prove:

> Consider arbitrary $n$ by $n$ matrix $\bf A$ matrix
>   and  $n$ by $n$ elementary matrix $\bf E$ such that
>
> $$\mathbf{E}_{i,j} = \begin{cases} \mathbf{I}_{i,j},  & i ≠ r\\[2ex]
>  \mathbf{I}_{i,j} + k\mathbf{I}_{d,j},  & i = r \\ \end{cases}$$
>
> Prove that
>
> $$[\mathbf{EA}]_{i,j} = \begin{cases} \mathbf{A}_{i,j},  & i ≠ r\\[2ex]
>  \mathbf{A}_{i,j} + k\mathbf{A}_{d,j},  & i = r \\ \end{cases}$$
>
> Note that that $1≤r≤n$ and $1 ≤ d ≤ n$ and $k$ is a scalar.

My attempt:

Take arbitarary $[\mathbf {EA}]_{i,j}$, $i ≠ r$

We have

$$\begin{align}[\mathbf{EA}]_{i,j} & = \sum_{x = 1}^{n}\mathbf{E}_{i,x}\mathbf{A}_{x,j} \\
& = \sum_{x = 1}^{n}\mathbf{I}_{i,x}\mathbf{A}_{x,j} = \mathbf{A}_{i,j}
\end{align}$$

Now take arbitarary $[\mathbf {EA}]_{i,j}$, where $i = r$

$$\begin{align}[\mathbf{EA}]_{i,j} & = \sum_{x = 1}^{n}\mathbf{E}_{i,x}\mathbf{A}_{x,j} \\
& = \sum_{x = 1}^{n}[\mathbf{I}_{i,x} + k\mathbf{I}_{d,x}]\mathbf{A}_{x,j} \\
& = \sum_{x = 1}^{n}\bigl(\mathbf{I}_{i,x}\mathbf{A}_{x,j} + k\mathbf{I}_{d,x}\mathbf{A}_{x,j}\bigr) \\
& = \sum_{x = 1}^{n}\mathbf{I}_{i,x}\mathbf{A}_{x,j} + k\sum_{x = 1}^{n}  \mathbf{I}_{d,x}\mathbf{A}_{x,j} \\ 
& = \mathbf{A}_{i,j} + k\mathbf{A}_{d,j}
\end{align}$$

As desired. $\square$

Is it correct?

---